# Azure ARM SDK to Create APP Managed Certificates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

i need to add custom domains with SSL binding from my web application in Azure using ARM SDK.
i have successfully created the domains but now i want to bind SSL on that domain, for that i need to Create the SSL with Azure ARM SDk.

i have tried with ARM SDK, but dont find the way to create it. here is the code

```
   var client =
                new ArmClient(new ClientSecretCredential(Config.TenantId, Config.ClientId, Config.ClientSecret));
```

var certifcate3 = client.GetAppServiceCertificateResource(
AppServiceCertificateResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(Config.SubscriptionId, Config.ResourceGroup,
"fyzz.in-mglz", "fyzz.in"));